# Calculating the difference between two datetimes?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

cur_time = datetime.now()
cur_time = pytz.utc.localize(cur_time)

rr_name = 'xx_20211005141746.txt'
rr_time =  re.search('_(.*).txt', rr_name).group(1)
rr_time =  datetime.strptime(rr_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

tzone = "Europe/London"
hb_time = pytz.utc.localize(rr_time).astimezone(pytz.timezone(tzone))
                    
diff = cur_time - hb_time

l_heared = round((diff.total_seconds() / 60), 2)
```

The difference between `cur_time` and `rr_time` is around 6 minutes, which is 360 seconds. How comes delta gives me back `77.65` seconds...

Please note `cur_time`  and `rr_name` are native datetimes

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? Yes, the difference is "*around* 6 minutes" – namely 5 minutes, 37 seconds, 525332 microseconds. What else did you expect?

Comment: Also, be careful in editing the question, leave some track when you change the context, as now my answer looks a bit out of topic (the original error was different)

Comment: what is `hb_time`?

Comment: Please take a look at the [mre] page. If you are unsure about the datetime calculations, leave out the filename and re stuff. If you are unsure about the filename and re stuff, leave out the datetime calculations. Don't depend on the "current time", since it is not reproducible. Either way, please make sure the example is minimal *but complete*.

Comment: Excuse, edited it (again)

Comment: I assume `'xx_20211005141746.txt'` is a file name; if the timestamp represents local time (as set in your operating system), then all the localization is not needed. Just parse to naive datetime and calculate the timedelta.

Comment: Yes its a filename, If I dont use the local time I have a 1 hour gap because the time of the filename is 1 hour behind the time of the os

Comment: so the date/time in the filename, does it represent local time?

Comment: No its the local time - 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set the correct time zone for date/time stored in the filename directly, don't set it to UTC first and then convert:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+ ; there is backports.zoneinfo for older versions
# import pytz

now = datetime.now(ZoneInfo('UTC'))
# now = datetime.now(pytz.UTC)
print(now.astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/London')))
# 2021-10-05 14:58:43.957950+01:00

rr_name = 'xx_20211005141746.txt' # time zone Europe/London in filename ...
rr_time =  re.search('_(.*).txt', rr_name).group(1)
rr_time =  datetime.strptime(rr_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/London'))
# rr_time = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(datetime.strptime(rr_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
print(rr_time)
# 2021-10-05 14:17:46+01:00

l_heared = round(((now-rr_time).total_seconds() / 60), 2) 
print(l_heared, "minutes ago")
# 40.97 minutes ago
```

---

### when this will fail

actually, since the filename's timestamp does not provide a UTC offset, this will fail for a DST transition *summer -> winter time* because the wall clock would show 1 AM for *two hours*! Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

tz = ZoneInfo("Europe/London")
tzutc = ZoneInfo("UTC")

dt = [datetime(2021, 10, 30, 23, tzinfo=tzutc) + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(4)]
dt = [d.astimezone(tz) for d in dt]

for d in dt: print(d)
# 2021-10-31 00:00:00+01:00
# 2021-10-31 01:00:00+01:00
# 2021-10-31 01:00:00+00:00 # DST change, 1 AM appears for two hours!
# 2021-10-31 02:00:00+00:00

t_ref = datetime(2021, 10, 31, 3, tzinfo=tzutc)
for t in dt: print(f"{t} -> age: {t_ref-t}")
# 2021-10-31 00:00:00+01:00 -> age: 4:00:00
# 2021-10-31 01:00:00+01:00 -> age: 3:00:00
# 2021-10-31 01:00:00+00:00 -> age: 2:00:00 # only correct because input is aware datetime with correct UTC offset
# 2021-10-31 02:00:00+00:00 -> age: 1:00:00

# ---------- DST winter -> summer works fine though: ----------

dt = [datetime(2021, 3, 28, tzinfo=tzutc) + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(4)]
dt = [d.astimezone(tz) for d in dt]

for d in dt: print(d)
# 2021-03-28 00:00:00+00:00
# 2021-03-28 02:00:00+01:00 # DST change, 1 AM is skipped
# 2021-03-28 03:00:00+01:00
# 2021-03-28 04:00:00+01:00

t_ref = datetime(2021, 3, 28, 3, tzinfo=tzutc)
for t in dt: print(f"{t} -> age: {t_ref-t}")
# 2021-03-28 00:00:00+00:00 -> age: 3:00:00
# 2021-03-28 02:00:00+01:00 -> age: 2:00:00 # this time no ambiguity
# 2021-03-28 03:00:00+01:00 -> age: 1:00:00
# 2021-03-28 04:00:00+01:00 -> age: 0:00:00
```

Comment: My local time is UTC+2, the datetime used in the file is UTC+1. I have a gap of 1 hour.  The time in filename should actually have +1 hour.... but I cant change the filename because its a changing variable

Comment: I have python version 3.7.7

Comment: @ManCity10 I've included the pytz option. With Python 3.7.7, you can still use the backports.zoneinfo module or dateutil, which follows the same semantics as zoneinfo.

Comment: I could not install zoneinfo.

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\backports\\__init__.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.`

Comment: How comes now is two hours behind my real time? which is right now 16:46 in CEST

Comment: @ManCity10 ok Anaconda is a pain if you ask me ^^ you should be able to make this working fine with `pytz`. Concerning variable `now`, in my code it is UTC; CEST is two hours ahead of UTC, hence the 2 hours offset. Actually, it doesn't matter to which tz you set `now`, you could also use `datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))` - important thing is that it *has* a defined tz.

Comment: Im confused...so at the end of this month our time in West Europe will switch from UTC+2 summer time to UTC+1 winter time. London will switch from UTC+1 summer time to UTC+0 winter time. The time mentioned in the filename will always stay UTC+1 weather its winter or summer. So during our winter `now` and `filetime` will be equal..(both UTC+1) will thins go good then? or do I have to change things in my code again...im afraid I will see 1 hour gaps in the future

Comment: @ManCity10 actually, this might fail for some cases, see my edited answer. The problem is that your filename does not specify the UTC offset.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `total_seconds` method:

```
print(f'{delta.total_seconds()} seconds')
```

output: `337.525332 seconds`

Comment: Why? Whats the difference?

Comment: delta is not a string, but a `timedelta` object, if you use `str(delta)` you will get the string representation of this object, which is **not** the total number of seconds (but `'0:05:37.525332'`)

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: **How does it not work?** It works for me, so either you are not running it on the same data, or something might be wrong with your python/timedelta version (is it recent? although the likeliest it option #1)

Comment: I updated my code so you can see it. Please run it and tell me.

Comment: You need `print(f'{l_heared} seconds')` not `print(f'{delta} seconds')`

Comment: I did not downvote your question. True your answer works, but for other data it does not work....

Comment: @ManCity10 then please provide this data, up to now it worked well, you just had typed the wrong variable

Comment: okay I provided the actual data, see my edited question. btw I will give you an upvote, idk who downvoted you...